# Problem in IE8 with toggle()

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

Here: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Anyone knows why the second example (Hello and Good Bye Example) does not work in IE8 ?

Comment: Do you mean the "Toggles all paragraphs" example?

Answer (score 1):

*Possibly* because the script is not within a `$(document).ready(...` block, as follows:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("p").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Unfortunately, I am unable to test in IE8. It works fine in Safari, Firefox and Chrome.